# Assigning window handles to variables in cmd to script moving windows around

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vlc

I'm using VLC's clone feature to display the same video on extended displays using the same controls. These windows are borderless, so I cannot move them around using a mouse. Per default, VLC opens them on the main display on top of each other.

I want to write a script that moves those windows to different coordinates.

I've tried using cmdow.exe to move open windows around. However, I need to address them individually. The only difference is their Handle. My output looks like this:

```
C:\cmdow.exe "VLC (Direct3D9 output)"
Handle  Lev  Pid -Window status- Image   Caption
0x1E084A 1 17740 Res Ina Ena Vis vlc     VLC (Direct3D9 output)
0x170762 1 17740 Res Ina Ena Vis vlc     VLC (Direct3D9 output)
```

Of course, the Handle values will change every time VLC is reopened.

How do I assign these values to variables in a script?

Comment: So which portion of each string do you want? the entire string? parts off it?

Comment: Did you try Alt+Space+M to enable move mode for the borderless window? Use the arrow keys to move the window, or the mouse after pressing an arrow key.

Comment: Anyway, for a task like this in CMD you can use a `for /f` loop to process the output of the command, line by line. It implements basic tokenizing of a line into `%[a-z]` variables.

Comment: Here is Windows source code for listing Windows https://pastebin.com/BfvdFkBq

Comment: Thanks for your replies, sorry for the delay. @GerhardBarnard In this case I want the strings "0x1E084A" and "0x170762". I know this sounds kind of basic, but I couldn't find anything for this table-like output, so anything to push me in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: @eryksun move mode would be a great solution as well, but I tried it and doesn't seem to work with VLC.

Comment: `for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('cmdow.exe "VLC (Direct3D9 output)"') do echo %%i` would take only the first token from the output and echo it.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, this is exactly what I needed! The last thing I need now is to assign them to variables. My code looks like this:
``for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('cmdow.exe "VLC (Direct3D9 output)"') do (
 set "handle1=%%i"
)
echo Handles are %handle1% and %handle2%``
The loop overwrites the first variable ``&handle1&`` every iteration, how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you want to set variables (which is not needed) you would never know the amount of lines returned, we can therefore create an array of variables with values:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('cmdow.exe "VLC (Direct3D9 output)"') do (
   set /a cnt+=1
   set handle!cnt!=%%i
)
for /l %%a in (1,1,%cnt%) do echo !handle%%a!
```

The `for /l` loop will simply be able to allow you to use each variable set, whether 1 or 1000

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you very much! The ``/l`` loop may contain an error since it's output for me was just ``handle1`` and ``handle2``, but I was able to accomplish what I wanted to nonetheless.